# Duel Entries for desktop entries in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: upgrade

I just upgrade my Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 and found that it has created dual entries for `Home` `External hard drive` `Trash` and every other folder present inside the Desktop. From the 2 entries, one is clickable and the other is not!

Is this a bug or some OS error from my side?

[sorry for the tags, the platform was not allowing me to choose the appropriate one]

[image]

And this is the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep -E "nautilus|nemo"`

[image]

Comment: Do you have Nemo installed. Please add the output of `dpkg -l | grep -E "nautilus|nemo"` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Updated!

Comment: Nemo is not installed, then it maybe some other problem. Maybe GNOME Shell extenstions overlap

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for this reason Each user now has their own Home directory.

> [image]

[reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/723039/whats-new-in-ubuntu-21.04-hirsute-hippo/)

Comment: This looks more like having two applications (Nautilus and Nemo for example) which manage desktop area.